# Typescript returns unknown for generic only on undefined input

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a generic env field getter function and currently have this:

```js
export interface Config {
  readonly PORT: number;
  readonly DATABASE_URL: string;
  // ... other fields
}
const config: Config = Object.freeze({
  ENVIRONMENT,
  PROJECT_NAME,
  PORT: parseInt(getEnvVariable('PORT', '9000'), 10),
  DATABASE_URL: getEnvVariable('DATABASE_URL'),
  AWS_REGION,
});

function getEnvVariable<T>(name: string, defaultValue?: T): T | string {
  const val = process.env[name];

  if (val) {
    return val;
  }

  if (defaultValue) {
    return defaultValue;
  }

  throw new Error(`Missing environment variable: ${name}`);
}
```

and I'm currently getting the error:

```
Type 'Readonly<{ ENVIRONMENT: string; PROJECT_NAME: string; PORT: number; DATABASE_URL: unknown; AWS_REGION: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Config'.
  Types of property 'DATABASE_URL' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[image]

For some reason if my `defaultValue` input is `undefined`, it will give this error, even though I do a truthy check.

How would I fix this without using an `''` as the `defaultValue`?

Comment: Looks like I had to do this: 
`getEnvVariable<string>('DATABASE_URL'),`

Comment: You could use a default generic type argument as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpx27m); does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah that works out better than having to explicitly define it as a string since most fields are strings anyway

Comment: I removed it from my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't pass in a `defaultValue` argument to `getEnvVariable`, then the compiler has no *inference site* for the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`.  So inference fails, and `T` falls back to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), which is implicitly [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).

If you'd like `T` to fall back to something else, you can use a [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) as shown here:

```
function getEnvVariable<T = string>( 
// default type arg ----> ^^^^^^^^ 
  name: string, defaultValue?: T
): T | string { /* impl */ }
```

Then you'll get the desired behavior when `defaultValue` isn't supplied:

```
const unsuppliedDefault = getEnvVariable("Y");
// const unsuppliedDefault: string
```

without changing the behavior when it is:

```
const suppliedDefault = getEnvVariable("X", Math.random());
// const suppliedDefault: string | number
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wArJgCzgMyghDgHIxsdSAoagUwA9JY5gA7GOqfZAYzrgBhCG3zAA5nADe1OHLhQ6yACYiANgE9MAeQBKAFQBccNgFcQAIy4BuWfMUr1WgCIBBfa4BCrgMoBRAH0AVV0AGWNUGCh2cVt5OAB6BLgAOjS4CFwuAmA6NWVUagBfal4RSLgy0QljYWrJAF44bQsAKzpeGBTCOjoALzoAChl4jD0jOAooVDoASQ5B8ToYPzYANwA1ZGjkCzUh0jGDUgAaMgBOAAZr0gBKM4BGS-u7OTcPb39gsOMllfWtjs9gd3l5fIEQqE7idirdbNR8KY2J1gCI4H9VpttsBdvsADz6OBNSLRNjiAB8gzYyBAdAiURiZ2UdB4pjUMC2alMdAA-MZ9Ld+XAAD5wEkxaSvSrleBrZBqImTIj8VCoFJ0dYAbWptIAuvD4sB8HBBnK1LdJfF4ooYKYoGw4Ga4vISlKjSbmaz2ZzuRaRla5Da7Q7Pcg2Rz5dznXJXfFcEQAO4mOhJvxQIhQQYAAwAssBVRKNWtgEQ2LSOI7sbi6XAACRSHV0IpZuHFWhVCpI1CmMBgNS5ZTOFlh9mKjEAqvAwYAIgAmtPW0lpWxOyue32B0OvTB6aTxO2ZWL1-26IPh+Gx8tMYCcVPpwANadnHOUFJQZBsVQgQa3RfJDvwN2vYnme267hKopmJYXC0LQQA)